# Why both ovals located at the same XY?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent, java-2d

I declared and built an array of two Balls instances ' m_ball[0]=new Ball(400,400,400,180);' & ' m_ball[1]=new Ball(400,400,400,0);' with different parameter values (180 and 0) but for some reason it seems that this different values get reset to 0 when the Timer start running and than both balls place on the same XY location. Can someone see why? I'm new in programming, Many Thanks... .

```
//This is main
public class BBDemo extends JApplet{        
    ...........
    }
}//endclass BBDemo

public class BBPanel extends JPanel {
    BallInBox m_bb;   // The moving ball panel ///in order to take the Timer->setAnimation from m_bb

    //========================================================== constructor
    /** Creates a panel with the controls and moving ball display. */
    BBPanel() {
        //... Create components
        m_bb = new BallInBox();   // The moving ball panel 
        .........
        startButton.addActionListener(new StartAction());

        .........  

    }
}//endclass BBPanel   

public class BallInBox extends JPanel {
    private Ball m_ball[]= new Ball[2];
    //... Instance variables for the animation
    private int   m_interval  = 40;  // Milliseconds between updates.
    static Timer m_timer;           // Timer fires to animate one step.
    static int j;
    private Color Pigment;

    //=================================================== constructor
    /** Set panel size and creates timer. */
    public BallInBox() {
        .........
        m_timer = new Timer(m_interval, new TimerAction());
        addMouseListener(new PressBall());
        m_ball[0]=new Ball(400,400,400,180);  
        m_ball[1]=new Ball(400,400,400,0);
    }
    public void setAnimation(boolean turnOnOff) {
        if (turnOnOff) {
            m_timer.start(); j=1; // start animation by starting the timer.
        } else {
            m_timer.stop();  j=0; // stop timer
        }
    }
    //======================================================= paintComponent
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);  // Paint background, border
        ........
        g.setColor(Pigment);
        m_ball[0].draw(g);           // Draw the ball.
        m_ball[1].draw(g);  
    } 

    class TimerAction implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            m_ball[0].setBounds(getWidth(), getHeight());          
            m_ball[0].move();  // Move the ball.
            m_ball[1].setBounds(getWidth(), getHeight());        
            m_ball[1].move();  // Move the ball.
            repaint();      // Repaint indirectly calls paintComponent.   
        }
    }
    }
}//endclass

public class Ball {
    //... Constants
    final static int DIAMETER = 50;
    //... Instance variables
    static int m_x;           // x and y coordinates upper left
    static int m_y;

    ......    
    //public int deg=90;    // Pixels to move each time move() is called.
    public int deg;
    public int offset=400;

    //======================================================== constructor
    public Ball(int x, int y, int offset, int deg) {
        m_x = x;
        m_y = y;
    }
    .........
    }
    //============================================================== move
    public void move() {
        double degrees=(double) deg;
        double radians=Math.toRadians(degrees);
        double Sinu=Math.sin(radians);
        double Sinu200=Math.sin(radians)*300;
        int SinuInt=(int) Sinu200;
        m_y=offset+SinuInt;
        double Cos=Math.cos(radians);
        double Cos200=Math.cos(radians)*300;
        int CosInt=(int) Cos200;
        m_x=offset+CosInt;
        deg++;   // j--;
        if (deg==360) deg=0;

    }

    //============================================================== draw
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.fillOval(m_x, m_y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
    }
    //============================================= getDiameter, getX, getY   
    public int  getDiameter() { return DIAMETER;}           
    public int  getX()        { return m_x;}
    public int  getY()        { return m_y;}
    //======================================================== setPosition
    public void setPosition(int x, int y) {                     
        m_x = x;
        m_y = y;
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 0):

In your Ball constructor, both `offset` and `deg` are not set. Try:

```
public Ball(int x, int y, int offset, int deg) {
    m_x = x;
    m_y = y;
    this.offset = offset;
    this.deg = deg;
}
```

Comment: - Tried that, I see no change... 'deg' is still with the same value for both Balls.

Comment: Take a look at VGR answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Ball` class, `m_x` and `m_y` are static, so they are shared by all instances of `Ball`.  Removing the word `static` from their declarations should help.